# Bootstrap issues with nested div centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a nested div in bootstrap that's also inside of a wrapper.

Basically it's sticking to the left of my wrapper instead of relatively centering itself.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper center-block">  
<P>
The panels below need to be centered so they dont stay left.
They aren't supposed to line up with this paragraph, but be offset so that it looks "fluid"<br />
i.e. stop here<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;v
</P>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 center-block">
        <!-- WHY WONT THIS NESTED DIV CENTER!?-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Test panel </strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer col-sm-10 center-block">
    <p><small>test footer</small>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    max-width:1200px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I was thinking about making *another* wrapper but this just seems excessive. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

With Css, you can use span to put text and it will shrink it. Then you can center it with `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` Or the `div` (needs a `width`) and make the same. If it's the text, then `text-align:center;`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As per Manuel's suggestion I ended up doing this:

**Changed**:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 center-block">
```

**To**:

```
<div class="wrapper2 center-block">
```

**Added CSS**:

```
.wrapper2{
    max-width:600px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Alternatively**:

```
<div class="center-block" style="max-width:600px;">
```

Works just the same.